# Type 'Bunny' already defines a member called 'OnTriggerEnter2D' with the same parameter types | How to make multiple collision in single script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add multiple collider in my Bunny script but it showing error mention below:

> Type 'Bunny' already defines a member called 'OnTriggerEnter2D' with the same parameter types

This is my code:

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D CoinCollider)
{
    if(CoinCollider.GetComponent<Coin>())
    {
        coinCount += 1;
        Destroy(CoinCollider.gameObject);
    }
} 
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D DiamondCollider)
{
    if(DiamondCollider.GetComponent<Diamond>())
    {
        DiamondCount += 1;
        Destroy(DiamondCollider.gameObject);
    }
} 

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Finish"))
    {
        other.gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
        gameOver();
    }
}
```

How to make multiple collision in single script?

Comment: You would use some form of conditional inside the single method to say if i hit wall do this ground so that etc

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single `OnTriggerEnter2D` method that receives a `Collider2D` as an argument. Merge your three methods into one and use `if`/`else if`/`else` statements.

The examples below are made using the code that you provided.

## Example 1

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.GetComponent<Coin>())
    {
        coinCount += 1;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
    else if (collision.GetComponent<Diamond>())
    {
        DiamondCount += 1;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Finish"))
    {
        collision.gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
        gameOver();
    }
}
```

## Example 2

If you wish to keep all your 3 methods separate, you can rewrite them into custom methods that are all called from a single `OnTriggerEnter2D` method.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.GetComponent<Coin>())
    {
        TakeCoin(collision.gameObject);
    }
    else if (collision.GetComponent<Diamond>())
    {
        TakeDiamond(collision.gameObject);
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Finish"))
    {
        FinishAt(collision);
    }
}

private void TakeCoin(GameObject coin)
{
    coinCount += 1;
    Destroy(coin);
}

private void TakeDiamond(GameObject diamond)
{
    DiamondCount += 1;
    Destroy(diamond);
}

private void FinishAt(Collider2D finish)
{
    finish.gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
    gameOver();
}
```